# Grangertest in R

Tags: r, time-series, causality

does someone knows what I am doing wrong?
I tried everything I've seen on the internet to perform the Grangertest.
The structure of my data is:

```
structure(list(Belgium = c(10786, 9902, 11119, 10218, 10454, 
11014), Netherlands = c(14929, 13905, 14994, 14753, 15031, 15386
), Date = structure(c(14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761
), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the codes I've tried is:

```
grangertest(Netherlands ~ Belgium, order = 1, data = df_NLBG_tf)
grangertest(Netherlands, Belgium, order = 1)
```

The error I keep getting is:
Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I tried to make the date numeric which also gave the same error.

Comment: I tried replicating your problem but I couldn't do it, as it ran without any issues.

Comment: I concur with @VishalA.  This suggests a problem with function masking or some other sort of name conflict.  I suggest restarting your R session, ensuring the global environment is empty, loading the required packages (which you should have mentioned in your question) and trying again.

Comment: Ive used the package: lmtest. No clue why it is not working. Even reinstalled R.